# Proof that intersection of two spectra is a spectrum.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let $A$ be a sentence of the predicate calculus with identity.
The *spectrum of $A$* is the set of positive integers $n$ such that $A$ has a model of cardinality $n$. We shall call a *spectrum* a set $X$ of positive
integers, such that $X = spectrum(A)$ for some $A$.

I want to show that *if $X$ and $Y$ are spectra, then $X \cup Y$ and $X\cap Y$ are spectra*.

Here http://www.math.psu.edu/simpson/ I have found the following **proof**:

Assume that $X$ is the spectrum of $A$ and $Y$ is the spectrum of $B$. Then $X \cup Y$ is the spectrum of $A \lor B$. Also, $X\cap Y$ is the spectrum of $A \land B$, ***provided
A and B have no predicates in common except the identity predicate*** $^{(*)}$.
To arrange for this, replace B by an analogous sentence in a different
language.

My question is: why do we need the hypothesis $^{(*)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that when they have no overlapping predicates, the way we put an $A$-satisfying structure on a set doesn't affect the way we can put a $B$-satisfying structure on the same set. If they overlap, though, you could get into a problem where $A$ and $B$ demand contradicting things.

For example, let the language for both $A$ and $B$ consist of a unary relation symbol $U$. Let $A$ be the sentence "$\forall x(U(x))$" and $B$ be the sentence "$\exists x(\neg U(x))$." Then:

- $Spec(A)=\mathbb{N}$,
- $Spec(B)=\mathbb{N}$, but
- $Spec(A\wedge B)=\emptyset$.

More interesting examples are of course possible, but this one illustrates the point.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear!