# properties of the spectrum in predicate logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, spectra

I want to proof that the set of spectra is closed under union and intersection. 
I know that it works somehow by assuming that the languages of the two formulas $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are disjoint and considering $\phi_1 \vee \phi_2$ and $\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2$, but I have no idea why we can assume that they are disjoint without loss of generality.

I'd appreciate any help for this exercise.

Comment: Is anything unclear (definitions etc.)?

Comment: I think you only need to have disjoint languages for the intersection. And you need  two disjoint languages in order to create sentences which can't directly contradict each other in your model. This can be done without loss of generality because the join of those two sentences can be formulated in the union of those two languages.

Comment: Also maybe this helps you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321194/proof-that-intersection-of-two-spectra-is-a-spectrum

Comment: @thehardyreader Thanks, thehardyreader, your answer and the link did help me very much. So we are allowed to assume that they are disjoint simply because otherwise we  can take any other language for the second formula, right?

Du machst derzeit auch Logik an der TU oder? Wir könnten unsere Beispiele in Zukunft gerne zusammentauschen, falls du möchtest.